# Minor alignment issue in Developer Beta tab in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story, firefox

There is a minor alignment issue in the Developer Story Beta tab. It bottom line is not matching with the remaining tab's bottom line in the Firefox browser.

It is not affecting the readability, just see the issue so want to report here.

Zoom: `100%`
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
Firefox version: `45.0.2`

*Note: Really need a sharp eye to see the issue !!! Expand the image to see the clear issue*

> [image: Bottom line alignment issue]

---

**UPDATE On May 9 :**

The bottom line is entirely removed now in Firefox.

> [image: No Bottom line]

Comment: Wow. Sharp eye. I'm sure that the beta superscript is causing this.

Comment: @BeshoyHanna May be, but the same is not happened in chrome or IE, there also the superscript exist

Comment: From the title I thought you were talking about the developer edition of firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Developer story alignment issue is fixed in the Firefox browser.

Verified in SO version: `rev 2016.10.12.4070`
Firefox version: `49.0.1`

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Alignment issue fixed]