# Bottom border is missing in questions page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, new-nav

In the [Question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) there is an alignment issue with the tabs list container. The bottom line is missing.
Its happening for [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) also.

Firefox: 46.0.1
Chrome: 50.0.2661.94
IE : 11.0.30
Zoom: 100%
OS: Windows 10

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Tabs list bottom border]

Same kind of [alignment issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322037/minor-alignment-issue-in-developer-beta-tab-in-firefox) for Developer Story Beta

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 50.0.2661.94 on Windows 7.

Comment: Also reproduced on IE11, also Windows 7.

Comment: I don't reproduce on W7 & FF 46

Comment: @ThomasAyoub :  It was happened 12 hours ago, hope after some time it was fixed. But the moderator is not yet changed the status to `status-completed`.